# Installed libxfce4util not found in CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, xfce, centos-7, xfce4

I installed the libxfce4util with no error in CentOS7.

[image]

But when I configure exo-0.10.3, the computer prompts me that libxfce4util was not found:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` command before configure exo,computer will find libxfce4util.